# button color doesn't change

Tags: android

I use this layout for button color (blue):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#449def" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#2f6699" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#449def"
                android:endColor="#2f6699"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#2f6699" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

When i try to change the color ,it doesn't change!It remains blue whatever changes i do.

I use in strings.xml:

```
<style name="mybuttons">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Here is a part from main.xml:

```
 <Button 
            android:id="@+id/select_c"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/choose_c"

            android:layout_marginTop="120dip"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            style="@style/mybuttons"
                />
```

Comment: Following on `Ollie C` answer you probably didn't set the selector background on to the button background because i tested your selector and works as expected.

Comment: @slukian:I updated.The problem is if i change the color it remains the same.

Comment: I don't think i understand what you try to achieve. You want the change the color of the button background, the one from the selector(where do you try to do this?)? I see you set some styles for the button but you don't have in that style anything for the button background color, just for the text of the button.

Comment: @slukian There is special background `selector` - it changes itself on focus/pressed/enabled states changes

Comment: @slukian:No,i don't have in style anything about background.I handle the colors in the first layout,where i have for example android:color="#449def" .My problem is that even if i change all the colors in this layout(first) the buttons remain blue.It looks like it stuck somehow!

Comment: @George Try to clean the project and then run it again.

Comment: Try to specify `android:state_pressed` for second item of selector.

Comment: @Jin35:that did it.I put at the first "focused" and then "pressed".Can you make it an answer?Thanks!

Comment: @slukian:I did clean but it did nothing.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify items in selector with `android:state_pressed` and `android:state_focused`

Answer (score 1):

You've not provided enough information to know what the problem is - where's the XML layout?

To use a selector drawable you need to create it (as you have done) but then apply it to your Button. I would expect to see an attribute like `background="@drawable/my_selector_drawable"` in there, to apply the button background to the button in your layout.